# Two-column index (pretty unequal columns) and database optimisation

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mariadb, index-tuning

I'm thinking about creating an index on a table like this:

```
primary | type | id
      1   a      10001
      2   a      10002
      3   b      10001
      n   b      1....
```

type will contain four values, ~ 95 % will be "a" (or 1, please don't care about the exact value/normalization). Also, 95 % of all queries will be looking for "a", too, in combination with a list of ids (~ one to five or so), like:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE type = 'a' AND id IN (...)
```

Basic task is to check a list of given id's for existence, so a "covering index" is the thing I basically want.

Now, as far as I understood, it's better to have the column first which reduces the result set most, which would be id. But on the other hand, an intelligent database engine could detect that most of the queries are about "a" and could keep only this branch of the index tree in memory, or, enough memory provided, all three indices as a "different" index each, as it would be better not to bother with all the "b" values.

Is a MySQL/MariaDB (just InnoDB backend) doing this kind of optimizations? Or any other thoughts? I'm not so interested in this table, more a general view on this case.

Thx in advance for all your comments ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many details missing.  InnoDB?  Is `SELECT id FROM table WHERE type = 'a' AND id IN (...)` exactly the query in question?  (It is rare to get only `id`, especially when you specify it in the `WHERE`.)  `id` is not the PK?  That is confusing.  Please change the question.

Regardless of cardinality, it is often better, and rarely worse, to use

```
INDEX(type, id)
```

for this and similar queries.

For one thing, this particular `SELECT` can be performed entirely in the BTree index.  Thus it is a "covering" index.  The `EXPLAIN SELECT...` will indicate such by saying "Using index".

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` with the actual query.

(Yes, I disagree with Károly Nagy.)

**More**

A "covering" index is an index that contains all the columns mentioned anywhere in the `SELECT`.

The best order for the columns is

1. First lay out the columns that are optimal for locating the rows.
2. Then add any extra columns (to "cover"), in any order.

I discuss step 1 in my [*Index cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .  Note that it says to put the '=' columns first.

So...

- `type` comes first because of '=';
- `id` comes next because it is needed to find the desired rows;
- Finally, there are no extra columns needed to "cover".

I will admit that there is a trade-off concerning "95% of the rows have type='a'".  Let me dig into details of two approaches:

Approach 1:  Secondary key `INDEX(id, type)`:

This will reach into the BTree index several times (one per `id`), then scan forward skipping over any (very few) rows that are not `type='a'`.  (In the documentation, see "MRR" for a discussion of this leapfrogging.)

Approach 2:  Secondary key `INDEX(type, id)`:

This will reach into the BTree index several times (one per combination (`'a', id`), then scan forward.  But it does not need to skip over any.  This Approach is not significantly faster when using 'a', but is significantly faster for `type='b'`.

Approach 3:  Secondary key `INDEX(id)`:

This is definitely slower than the others.  It must locate each `id` in the index, then reach over into the data to check `type`.  This bouncing back and forth between the index and the data will make it roughly twice as slow.  The optimizer notices this and *may* decide it would be faster to simply ignore the index and scan the entire table.

Comment: Updated the question. There are not that many details yet. Still, I'm interested in an explanation/reason for ordering the indexed fields in this way and how the database handles it.

Comment: I added More.  I hope I have answered your underlying question.  Keep in mind that different datatypes, indexes, etc, _may_ lead to variations on the answer.  If you have another table for which you have the same question, start a new Q&A to see if it I give you a different explanation.

Comment: Some of the issues that make _this_ Q&A different:  The PK is not involved; the columns seem 'short'; the 95%; `IN` (vs '=' or range); the desire for 'covering'; etc.  Change any of those, and the answer _may_ change.

Comment: Thx, I think approach 2 hit it and I'll go in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. The more selective column should come first unless it happens to be in a range condition.

Having `type` in the index will provide absolutely no benefits on the performance when you query for `type='a'`. It will however put some extra overhead on your indexes which may result in actual degradation of performance.

If `id` is always in the query with this cardinality I wouldn't bother having `type` in your index at all. Especially if `id` is unique.

Comment: No, id is not unique, guess that was a bit unclear from my side ;)

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying! Regardless, I don't think having `type` in the index gives you too much benefit. But of course always best to try in see in the specific use case and with the specific dataset.